# Is there a term for a character only there to die?

Tags: terminology

In some movies, you can tell when a character is there only to make a dramatic moment when he/she dies.

Is there a term for a character written specifically to die for dramatic purpose?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DisposableWoman http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CollateralAngst http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StuffedIntoTheFridge

Comment: Yeah, his name's Sean Bean.

Comment: @Mazura or Michelle Rodriguez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *redshirt* originiated in [Star Trek](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060028/) where security personnel wore red shirts and would frequently die during missions. The term has since spread beyond Star Trek and is often used these days for [a character whose death provides dramatic effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshirt_(character)).

Another commonly used expression is *sacrifical lamb* which comes from the Bible story where [Abraham sacrifices a lamb instead of his son](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+22). This phrase has also been adopted in literature annd films with a similar meaning i.e. [someone who is only there to die for dramatic effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacrificial_lamb#In_the_arts).

Comment: Ironically, if you went by the percentage that died for each shirt colour, goldshirts were the worst off. http://www.startrek.com/article/did-redshirts-really-die-more-often-on-tos

Comment: an extra..........